# Concept related to transaction?

Tags: database, concurrency, database-concurrency

I was reading about transactions in DBMS. Just get started with it. But I am super confused with one concept.

[image]

**Suppose initially A=100**

For T1 A=100 and doing A = A-50

For T2 temp would be 10 and change A=90. So T2 would write A=90.

Now when T1 is doing write(A) then it should write A=50 because it has done A=A-50. But it is showing T1 is writing A=90 same as T2.

Why it is happening?

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, example data should be *text* in your question.

Comment: @Stu Okay but what is correct ans for it?

Answer (score 0):

If A is a variable then it's context is shared accross the program, you should try to use a temporary value in calculations.

Comment: But shared memory is same for all the transaction